# How to add new column for each array inside foreach jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have three arrays returning as json and I would like to display each of the array in a new column. How can I achieve that?

Here is the `$.post` function

```
  $.post("/booking/times", {
      id: $("#user_id").val(),
      selectedDay: formattedDate
    },
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#dayTimes').empty();
      $(".loading-icon").hide();


      if (data.times.length == 0) {
           console.log("no available times");
      } else {
        $.each(data.times, function(index, value) {
          console.log(value);
        });
      }
    });
```

Here is the json output what I get from `console.log` inside the `each`:

```
{  
    "times":[  
        [  
            "10:30 - 11:00",
            "11:00 - 11:30",
            "11:30 - 12:00",
            "12:00 - 12:30",
            "12:30 - 13:00",
            "13:00 - 13:30",
            "13:30 - 14:00"
        ],
        [  
            "14:00 - 14:30",
            "14:30 - 15:00",
            "15:00 - 15:30",
            "15:30 - 16:00",
            "16:00 - 16:30",
            "16:30 - 17:00"
        ],
        [  
            "17:00 - 17:30",
            "17:30 - 18:00",
            "18:00 - 18:30",
            "18:30 - 19:00",
            "19:00 - 19:30",
            "19:30 - 20:00"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: based on your example json data, you want to display that in 3 columns?

Comment: @juntapao yes sir.

Answer (score 1):

try to put this inside your $.each, I sampled it to output in a table.

```
output = '<table border="1">';
$.each(value, function(index, row) {
    output += '<tr>';
    $.each(row, function(index, cell) {
        output += '<td>' + cell + '</td>';
    });
    output += '</tr>';
});
output += '</table>';
$('#div_element').html(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this**
*times is your array*

```
var table = $("<table></table>");
var thead = $("<thead></thead>");
var tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
var trhead = $("<tr></tr>");

for(var i=0;i<times.length;i++){

    $(trhead).append('<th>coloumn</th>');
    var trbody = $("<tr></tr>");
    for(j=0;j<times[i].length;j++){
        $(trbody).append('<td>'+times[i][j]+'</td>');
    }
    $(tbody).append($(trbody));

}
$(thead).append($(trhead));
$(table).append($(thead));
$(table).append($(tbody));
```

Answer (score 0):

@raqulka. What do you mean by to display each of the array in a new column?

If you want to Display the value in an array as string in html table. Then try following

```
$.post("/booking/times", {
      id: $("#user_id").val(),
      selectedDay: formattedDate
    },
    function(data) {

      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      console.log(data);
      $('#dayTimes').empty();
      $(".loading-icon").hide();


      if (data.times.length == 0) {
           console.log("no available times");
      } else {

        var tbl = document.createElement('table');
        tbl.style.width = '100%';
        tbl.setAttribute('border', '1');
        var tbdy = document.createElement('tbody');
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        $.each(data.times, function(index, value) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value.toString()))
            tr.appendChild(td)
        });
        tbdy.appendChild(tr);
        tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
        body.appendChild(tbl)
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was this.

```
    $.each(data.times, function(index, value) {
      // console.log(value);
      var timesColumns = '<div class="col-md-4">';
      $.each(value, function(key, value) {
        // console.log(value);
        timesColumns += '<div class="pretty superhoidjad-booking "><input name="available_times[]" class="available_times" type="checkbox" value="' + value + '"/><label><i class="mdi mdi-check"></i>' + value + '</label></div>';
        // console.log(times);
      });
      timesColumns += "</div>";
      console.log(timesColumns);
      $("#dayTimes").append(timesColumns);

    });
```